# How to build a pdf using xelatex.exe from cmd and allow to take packages that he needs from internet

Tags: xetex

I have read until now and looks possible to run xelatex from cmd and to allow to take all packages that he need from internet.
Does someone know how this command should look like?

Thanks

Comment: it is the same as pdftex. with texlive implementations you need to use `tlmgr` to update your installation  to add any missing packages. miktex implementations (I understand) have an option to automatically fetch packages, but I havem't got miktex so can not give details. It is not xetex-specific in either case

Comment: -enable-installer from xelatex help has done the job for me. Thanks